# Impossible evaluate LSTM model for valueErrore continuous-multioutput is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I cannot evaluate my model because i find this error when i try to print the accuracy of my model.
How can I evalueate my model? I use LSTM to generate new data from my dataset, i know different metrics like accuracy, precision and recall but every time i try to implement to my data generated i found this problem

```
#scaled is my dataset that i scaled and contain 6879 line with this value:

#array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
#       [0.        , 0.25      , 0.        , 0.07142857, 0.        ],
#       [0.        , 0.875     , 0.        , 0.07142857, 0.        ],
#       ...,
#       [0.98828125, 0.375     , 0.92050207, 0.5       , 0.        ],

from numpy import array

n_steps = 10
n_features = 5


def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

X, y = split_sequences(sequences=scaled, n_steps=n_steps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# define model
LSTM_model = Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False,activation='relu' ,input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
#model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
LSTM_model.add(Dense(n_features))
LSTM_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# fit model
LSTM_model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
LSTM_model.summary()

print(accuracy_score(ytest, LSTM_model.predict(xtest)[:,0,:]))



this is the error

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-0e337cd696dc> in <module>()
      1 #yhat = Conv1D_model.predict(X, verbose=0)
----> 2 print(accuracy_score(ytest, Conv1D_model2.predict(xtest)[:,0,:]))
      3 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    102     # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
    103     if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:
--> 104         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    105 
    106     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1** From the comments, this does not look like a classification problem, so `accuracy_score()` won't work since it requires unique, comparable labels and predictions.

Without seeing how your predictions look (compared to your true labels), the biggest problem I see is that you're passing predictions to `accuracy_score()` and the comparisons  will almost never match. `ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported` most likely refers to the fact that predictions are confidence float values, meanwhile true labels are integers or int-like, such as `0.` or `1.`. Your predictions most likely include continuous values like `0.9876` which will never match `0.` or `1.`. You need to discretize them with either some function or by rounding...probably.

`if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:` should also be an indicator that it's looking for either `[0, 1]` (binary), or `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]` (multiclass), or `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], ..., [n, m]]` (multilabel).

["the set of labels predicted for a sample must exactly match the corresponding set of labels in y_true"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)

Do something like this:

```
preds = LSTM_model.predict(xtest)  # gets predictions as floats
preds = np.rint(preds)  # rounds to nearest int, where >=.5 becomes 1
print(accuracy_score(ytest, preds)
```

**Edit0:** You are also missing an activation function in your final `Dense` layer. Otherwise you're getting a roughly linear representation of the previous layer's output through `n_features` neurons as values.

```
LSTM_model.add(Dense(n_features, activation="softmax"))
LSTM_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
```

Comment: Hi Djinn, i try your solution but don t work, this is the error:


IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed.
This is the shape:

xtrain.shape, xtest.shape, ytrain.shape, ytest.shape
((5151, 10, 5), (1718, 10, 5), (5151, 5), (1718, 5))

all are float value like xtrain:
array([[[0.33007812, 0.75      , 0.89121336, 0.07142857, 0.        ],
        [0.3203125 , 0.125     , 0.81589955, 0.5714286 , 0.        ],
        [0.3203125 , 0.625     , 0.81589955, 0.71428573, 0.        ],
        ...,

Comment: Remove the brackets after the prediction call.

Comment: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and multilabel-indicator targets`

did you know why? i know is a very simple problem but is 1 day that i m stuck on that

Comment: `(ytest, preds)
(array([[0.16601562, 0.25      , 0.44769874, 0.42857146, 0.        ],
        [0.07421875, 0.25      , 0.08786611, 0.8571429 , 0.        ],
        ...,
        [0.29101562, 0.125     , 0.76987445, 0.07142857, 0.        ],
        [0.28320312, 0.25      , 0.67364013, 0.5714286 , 0.        ]],
       dtype=float32), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0., -0.],
        ...,
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))`

Comment: Ahh I see the issue. You're missing an activation function on your final `Dense` layer. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Also, is your `ytrain` float values? Is this a classification problem? Or are you doing something else? If it's not classification, then you probably don't need to round your predictions.

Comment: i want to forecast my dataset to generate new value, this is the problem, than i need to compare new dataset generated with old dataset with precision, recall and other metrics

Comment: I updated the model and ran the code below but I get this error:

LSTM_model = Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False,activation='relu' ,input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
LSTM_model.add(Dense(n_features, activation="softmax"))
LSTM_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
LSTM_model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
preds = LSTM_model.predict(xtest)  # gets predictions as floats
preds = np.rint(preds)  # rounds to nearest int, where >=.5 becomes 1
print(accuracy_score(ytest, preds))

Comment: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and multilabel-indicator targets

Comment: You're getting that error because your `ytest` is continuous values. You can't classify into continuous values without representing them as discrete values. Precision, Recall, F1, etc, are meant for classification, either binary or multiclass. I don't see how you can use those metrics for what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes, xtrain,ytrain, xtest, ytest are all float value from dataset that i scaled

Comment: Maybe you can compare the generated dataset with the original and see how the points look on a plot. It should look how your scalings represent it.

Comment: so for your opinion i can t use precision, recall, accuracy or  Fscore?

Comment: Correct, those are classification metrics and you're not doing classification. If you were, for example, to use this new, generated data to train a classifier, then you could use those metrics on that new classifier. For example, if you wanted to compare the performance of two models trained on the two datasets.

Comment: did you know any metrics to compare 2 dataset?

Comment: Maybe something dealing with linear regression?